# Modern short-form German names for boys and girls

Tags: abbreviation, person-names, proper-noun

Gion is a short-form name for Johannes, a boy's name. What are other examples for German, Austrian or Swiss boys and girls?

Comment: Never heard "Gion" before. According to Wikipedia it is rätoromanisch

Comment: What are you looking for? (1) Names that are nowadays given to babies and that are etymologically the short forms of longer names? (2) Long names that are nowadays given to babies and that have a common short form? (3) Just short names curremtly given to babies (short in terms of letters or in terms of syllables), no matter how they are derived etymologically?

Comment: Supplementing @Uwe: 4) Names which can be used for girls as well as for boys?

Comment: @Lykanion Which German country are you from/in? and what is rätoromanisch? to the others, any short names for any gender or age, accompanied by the long-form names they are short forms of. thanks

Comment: Sorry, but questions asking for lists are not a good fit for SE sites as they are inherently opinion-based. VTC.

Comment: @user610620 I live in Germany. For Rätoromanisch, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romansh_language). Notably, it is not a german language.

Comment: oh. romansh yeah

Answer (score 1):

This website collects the most popular given names in Germany, ordered by year:

https://www.beliebte-vornamen.de/

Since short names are popular today, the lists will contain many short names, including short forms of longer names. Which names are short forms and which are short names (and which short names / forms aren't on the lists) is something you will have to research yourself. There are many websites listing names, so the information is free. It'll just take some of your time to assemble the information. Have fun!

Comment: the list fails to also show the long-forms of the short names.

Comment: @user610620 I believe that is what I said when I wrote that "[w]hich names are short forms and which are short names ... is something you will have to research yourself". Or in other words, to my knowledge there is no comprehensive list that collects all and only short forms of longer names and includes the long forms. I just gave you a starting point for your own research, because that is, I blieve, as close as you will get to your aim without some massive effort of your own.